# Which materials are white due to diffuse reflection, and which due to absorption/re-emission of all wavelengths?

Tags: visible-light, material-science, reflection, vision

Is there any way of knowing which white objects or materials are white due to emission of most or all wavelengths, and which due to diffuse reflection?

If there is one type of material I would like to know about especially, it is white textiles/fibers.....

Also white paint (titanium dioxide, e.g.)

Answer (score 1):

White textiles and paints have added materials, such as TiO2, to scatter light which results in diffuse reflection.

I'm not sure about your use of the term "emission."